# Inner Join 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables and I want to know how can I do a triple join with this type of setup if at all?

```
First Table: LOCATIONS_TABLE
locationID
websiteID
locationCity
locationState
locationCountry
locationURL

Second Table: PREF_TABLE
pref_ID
Pref_LocationID
Pref_WebsiteID
Pref_SavedTitle

Third Table: WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE
wbcatID
websiteID
WBLinkCategoryParentID
WBLinkTitle
WBLinkURL
```

the 2nd table is where the user has a store preference with a Pref_SavedTitle for their Locations they have saved for later reference.

The Current SQL Statement I have which only does a double inner join is...

```
SELECT 
LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationWebsiteID, 
LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationCity, 
LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationState, 
LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationCountry, 
LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationURL, 
PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle 
FROM PREF_TABLE INNER JOIN LOCATIONS_TABLE 
ON PREF_TABLE.Pref_LocationID = LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationID 
WHERE PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle = 'AlabamaPREF'
```

This returns sample data of...

```
LocationWebsiteID = 2 
locationCity = Mobile 
locationState = Alabama 
locationCountry = United States
locationURL = alabama.bmv.org
Pref_SavedTitle - AlabamaPREF
```

The 3rd table has the sample data of...

```
wbcatID = 1
websiteID = 2
WBLinkCategoryParentID = 0
WBLinkTitle = Alabama Resources
WBLinkURL = /alabama-resources
```

This does exactly what it needs to do which is returns me all of the LOCATION_TABLE items that equal the LocationID that was stored previously in the PREF_TABLE.

However I have a 3rd table that I need to add to this equation (Which is the Third Table) listed above.  I need to be able to link the Third Table on the websiteID somehow so that it knows the WBLinkTitle and WBLinkURL are associated with that specific websiteID

On the final output... I need to be able to pull the results for the columns...

```
LOCATIONS_TABLE.websiteID, 
LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationURL, 
WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.WBLinkTitle, 
WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.WBLinkURL
```

which based off my sample data would be...

```
websiteID = 2
locationURL = alabama.dmv.org
WBLinkTitle = Alabama Resources
WBLinkURL = /alabama-resources
```

[**SQLFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/391e4/5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATED v-1**

I've updated the answer according to your comment (now the 3rd table is inner-joined to `PREF_TABLE` and additional condition was added to the first join: `AND PREF_TABLE.Pref_WebsiteID = LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationWebsiteID` to prevent all-locations loading):

```
SELECT 
    LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationWebsiteID, 
    LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationCity, 
    LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationState, 
    LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationCountry, 
    LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationURL, 
    PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle,
    WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.WBLinkTitle,
    WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.WBLinkURL
FROM 
    PREF_TABLE 
    INNER JOIN LOCATIONS_TABLE 
        ON PREF_TABLE.Pref_LocationID = LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationID
           AND PREF_TABLE.Pref_WebsiteID = LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationWebsiteID
    INNER JOIN WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE 
        ON WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.websiteID = PREF_TABLE.Pref_WebsiteID 
WHERE 
    PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle = 'AlabamaPREF'
```

Comment: This actually returns ALL of the locations in the table and not just the ones that had Pref_SavedTitle listed as 'AlabamaPREF'

Comment: Still doing the same thing.  Its returning all the results inside the Locations table, its like the WHERE statement doesn't matter and is being ignored even though i have it exact replica as how you have it

Comment: Sorry - I think I didn't predict the precise behaviour. Please try now - the answer and query are updated and, I hope, should work now.

Comment: Still same thing.  Its just adding the SavedTitle to every row of the LOCATIONS table which the LOCATIONS_TABLE has 700 results, while the PREF_TABLE only has 8 results.  However its just listing out everything from LOCATIONS_TABLE for some reason and then setting the Pref_SavedTitle to everyone of the results

Comment: Could you tell whether your sql query marked as "**current**" in your question returned also the same results? Could you also try the query from the answer removing from it the 3rd table with its join and the joined columns and then try what the results will be ?

Comment: My current still outputs the exact same data as i listed above in the original.  I even added an SQL FIDDLE in the original post and at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/391e4/5 to give a prime example of some data i have

Comment: Thank you very much for the sql fiddle. Please tell me, didn't your query from the question also return ALL the locations from the table?

Comment: Nope as the SQL Fiddle example shows it only returns the ones that are set to AlabamaPREF

Comment: Please find in this SQL fiddle **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/391e4/11** there are 2 queries (from Question and from the Answer) combined together and you may see and compare the results of both. Please refer - thx in advance.

Comment: Hmm well your result does work perfectly fine according to SQLFiddle... Now I just gotta figure out why its not working on the live version lol.  Must be something stupid with a column or something.  Thanks a ton though! You have helped me out a lot

Comment: I'm really glad then. hope you will accomplish the task to the end. Regards :)