# Sqlite Double Inner Join for a sql.query statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have the following raw SQL statement, but i do NOT want to use an sql.rawquery  I want to know how to do this in an SQL.Query statement form for android.

```
String NewSqlstatement =  
    "SELECT "+
       "LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationWebsiteID, "+
       "LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationCity, "+
       "LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationState, "+
       "LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationCountry, "+
       "LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationUrl, "+
       "LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationID, "+
       "PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle, "+
       "WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.WBLinkTitle, "+
       "WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.WBLinkURL "+
     "FROM "+
       "PREF_TABLE "+
     "INNER JOIN "+
       "LOCATIONS_TABLE "+
     "ON "+
       "PREF_TABLE.Pref_LocationID = LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationID "+
     "INNER JOIN "+
       "WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE "+
     "ON "+
       "WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.WBLinkWebsiteID = PREF_TABLE.Pref_WebsiteID "+
     "WHERE "+
       "PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle = 'blah'";
```

I want to know how to do this in a SQL.QUERY, not a SQL.RAWQUERY....  I know the format of an sql.query and I've used it several times, I just don't know how to do a double inner join

Also how you going to downvote someone for trying to learn something new?

Answer (score 1):

`i do NOT want to use an sql.rawquery` - **WHY**?

Your `rawQuery()` issue is here:

```
"PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle = '?'";
```

You have to remove the **'** s from the **?** bound parameter.
Since Android handles the bound parameters automatically

So, leave just

```
"PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle = ?";
```

Comment: I don't want to use sql.rawquery...  I'm fully aware if i droped the ' ' it would work.  I just threw that in there last minute anyways.  Technically it was 'blah' before which i should of just left thats my mistake

Comment: Why don't you want to use `rawQuery()`? I only use that (for queries) in addition to `execSQL();` (for commands). **with** bound parameters, as shown.

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771315/inner-join-3-tables  I tried to do it (still trying to do it) with a rawQuery().  Even though its an exact replica, it doesn't work.  returns ALLLL my results but when done in SQLFiddle or something, it works perfectly fine.  By process of elimination all i can determine is that rawQUERY doesn't like crazy statements

Comment: And you are completely **wrong**. What can be done by `query`, can be done by `rawQuery()`. And BETTER, since you can write the full SQL statement string. I do query **6** joined tables (3 INNER JOINs and 2 LEFT JOINs) in a single query. And it works perfectly. I wouldn't call joining **3** tables a `crazy statement`.

Comment: Did you log the actual sql string your code generates, and then run that against the same database?

Comment: No, I did the **opposite**. I first verified the statement in `SQLManager`. I then imported it **AS IS** into my code. I then optimized it via `string.format`, to avoid repetitions and to introduce **table name changes on demand** AND finally bound the parameters by using the **?** placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

I think [SQLiteQueryBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) is what you want.  Here's one example of usage for inner joins:

http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sqlite-join-multiple-tables-example/

Comment: Lol i said i want to use sql.query so of course I want to use it?  I need to know how to convert the above into an SQL.QUERY

Comment: Oh, you want someone to write the code for you!  Well I would say give it a shot and ask specific questions when you run into trouble.  Did you look at the code in the tutorial? I think it's fairly similar to your situation.

Comment: I never asked anyone to write the code for me.  I was asking for assistance.  Linking a page to android builder doesn't help answer anything especially when I hinted strongly I already knew how to do a query itself.  If you know how to do it, then you don't have to answer my question using my exact statement.  You could easily do query(tablehere, "blah", "blah"....) etc

Comment: If you already know how to build a query using the query builder, then I don't understand the problem.  If you don't, maybe a link to a tutorial can help you.  I don't know what you would gain from different example code I might write than what's in that tutorial or probably several others you could  find.  So I guess I don't know how to help you, but if you can clarify I'm willing to try.